# Property 'randomUUID' does not exist on type 'Crypto'

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills

I was trying to use [crypto.randomUUID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID) in my angular app v13.1, but it seems not to be available. Gives us this error if you try:

> TS2339: Property 'randomUUID' does not exist on type 'Crypto'

It looks like support for it [was merged into Typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47445) version 4.6. Angular 13.1 is not compatible with TypeScript 4.6, gives us this error if you try:

> Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.4.2 and <4.6.0 but 4.6.3 was found instead.

Is there a way to polyfill the current implementation of `crypto.randomUUID` into TypeScript 4.5?

I wanted to avoid using [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) and its related TypeScript types directly, but I would be open to using it as a polyfill to TypeScript 4.5 if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

it's just

```js
 self.crypto.randomUUID();
```

Worked on typescript + angular project

Answer (score 2):

see npm [crypto-randomuuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-randomuuid) which is a polyfill

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works with Angular, but since this is one of the first results for this error in google...
This works for me in React:

> npm i @types/node@14.17.34

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by using `crypto['randomUUID']()`. But take care that this is not available in IE, if you want to provide support for IE.
In that case you can do something like
`if(typeof crypro !== undefined) { const id = crypto['randomUUID']() }`

Answer (score -1):

I tried this. TS v4.6.3 does work on angular 13.1

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Types for crypto.

```
npm install --save @types/node
```

```js
  uuid: string;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.uuid = self.crypto.randomUUID();
    console.log(this.uuid); // for example "36b8f84d-df4e-4d49-b662-bcde71a8764f"
  }
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-template-3zz6my?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: We definitely cannot use TS 4.6 on angular 13.1. The error I posted in my question comes from the angular compiler. Your stackblitz is running angular 13.3 of which the main added feature is [support](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2022/03/16/what-is-new-angular-13.3/) to TS 4.6

Comment: Yeah, StackBlitz was pumped to 13.3, though when testing I was quite sure I was on 13.1.